# Homebrew packages in PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have a bunch of libraries installed with homebrew but I don't know what the right way to get them in pkg-config's search path. Right now I have

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(find /usr/local/Cellar -name 'pkgconfig' -type d | grep lib/pkgconfig | tr '\n' ':' | sed s/.$//)
```

This works fine, but it does slow down my shell startup time, which now takes about 2 seconds. I'm sure that there's a better way built into homebrew, but I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Convert the `find` to a static list colon `:` separated PKG_CONFIG_PATH list to reduce launch time.

Step 1. Run `pkg-config --list-all` to determine what packages are already know by

```bash
pkg-config --list-all

# tidy         tidy - tidy - HTML syntax checker
# tesseract    tesseract - An OCR Engine
# …
```

Step 2. Run `find` to determine the `pkgconfig` directories that contain *.pc files.

```bash
### long form `find`
find /usr/local/Cellar -name 'pkgconfig' -type d | grep lib/pkgconfig | tr '\n' ':' | sed s/.$//
find /usr/local/Cellar -name 'pkgconfig' -type d | grep share/pkgconfig | tr '\n' ':' | sed s/.$//
# - or -
find /usr/local/Cellar -name 'pkgconfig' -type d | grep pkgconfig | tr '\n' ':' | sed s/.$//

### short form `find`
find / -name "pkgconfig" -print

# /usr/local/Cellar/abc/0.1.5/lib/pkgconfig:…/usr/local/Cellar/xyz/2.6/lib/pkgconfig
```

Step 3. Add the paths libraries of interest, *that are not already discoverable by `pkg-config`*, to PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

*Option: use a `/usr/local/Cellar/…` path which will need to be updated with each version number change.*

```sh
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/abc/0.1.5/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/abc/0.1.5/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/my/build/from/source/mmmm/0.1.5/lib/pkgconfig
```

*Options: When the Cellar is linked (typically) into `/usr/local/opt/…` then a version independent path can be found and used.*

```sh
sudo find / -name "uvw" -print
# /usr/local/Cellar/uvw
# /usr/local/opt/uvw
ls -l /usr/local/opt/uvw
# /usr/local/opt/uvw@ -> ../Cellar/uvw/4.2_1
```

Set these:

```sh
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/uvw/share/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/opt/xyz/lib/pkgconfig
```

---

Note: Apple ARM and Apple Intel have different homebrew `Cellar` locations.

- Apple ARM: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar`
- Apple Intel: `/usr/local/Cellar`

Comment: This is both beautiful and useful! Tyvm!

Comment: using /usr/local/opt/* is less likely to break when you upgrade homebrew packages vis a vis /usr/local/Cellar, IME.

Comment: @hd1 good point on using version independent links in path. Answer updated.

Comment: `long form 'find'` is excellent command but `grep lib/pkgconfig` is not enough sometimes. Because some libraries are living in `share/pkgconfig`  folder. Because of that if you change this grep filter to only `pkgconfig` will be better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Mac Mojave as `/usr/include` is [gone under Xcode 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes#3035623), and you have to install a separate package to get it back.

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

source: https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/232

Comment: It's not clear to me how this answers the question.  If you believe that it does answer the question, please explain how it does so. … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.